# How to change the default page size that display element in a grid to display more than 10 elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So i have a grid with kendo and i have to display 1580 elements. But by default it only display 10 and the user have to choose how many he wants. How to set the default value on 1580 ? I've looked for it with no sucess.

I put the code here :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DisplayGridResultatsPrestations>
    ()
     .Name("GridListeIdcc")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(c => c.CategoriePrestation);
         columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationPrestation);
         columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurPreconisee);
         columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurProposee);
         columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationResultat);
      })
      .Filterable()
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
      .Pageable(builder => builder.PageSizes(new[] { 1580, 1580 }))
      .DataSource(datasource => datasource
      .Ajax()
```

Comment: You mean `.PageSize(1580)`?

Comment: That will display my 1580 results in once ? because i can't put this it gives me the error cannot convert from 'int' to 'int[]'

Comment: This may help you http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-pagesize-dinamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.PageSize(1580)` within the `.DataSource()` like below. You may also have to remove what you have inside `.Pageable()` as well.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<displaygridresultatsprestations>()
    .Name("GridListeIdcc")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CategoriePrestation);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationPrestation);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurPreconisee);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurProposee);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationResultat);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(1580)
    )
)
```